# MySQL Multiple Joins 3 Table ( Bridge Table )

Tags: mysql

1st table **Courses** columns:

```
courseId|instructorId|desc|courseName|img|
```

2nd table **StudentCourses** columns:

```
studentCourseId|studentId
```

3rd table **UserData** columns:

```
userId|avatar|name
```

So knowing studentId,i am trying to get students owned courses with its instructors profiledata(in this case avatar and name)
result columns should be:

```
 courseId,courseName,desc,img,instructorsname,instructorsavatar
```

This query gives me students courseInfo but instructor data is not included.

```
SELECT Courses.courseId,Courses.img,Courses.courseName,Courses.`desc` FROM Courses JOIN StudentCourses ON StudentCourses.studentCourseId = Courses.courseId WHERE StudentCourses.studentId ="igkw11tkwa06kpmoe9o6hyytrq0qaqjq"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming that instructorId match with userid

```
    SELECT  Courses.courseId
            ,Courses.img
            ,Courses.courseName
            ,Courses.`desc` 
            , u1.name
            , u1.avatar
    FROM Courses 
    INNER JOIN StudentCourses ON StudentCourses.studentCourseId = Courses.courseId 
    INNER JOIN UserData u1 ON u1.userId = Courses.instructorId
    WHERE StudentCourses.studentId ="igkw11tkwa06kpmoe9o6hyytrq0qaqjq"
```